# How to Create a JSON Object and Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, json

I am wanting to get data from a phone (geoLocation data) and put that into a JSON Object and send that over a network to a database to be stored. I am unsure how to create this object and if it should be an array of objects. Also, how do I setup the object to receive new information as it updates to send to the server? Here is the code I currently have. I am using eclipse, phonegap, javascript and JSON.

```
var JSONID = 0;

    // Create a JSON Object Array
    geoLocJSON ();

    /* This is what I want my Object to look like.
    [   
        {
        "id" : 0,
        "geoLoc" : {
                        "Lat" : "",
                        "Long" : ""
                    },
        "direction" : {
                        "Alt" : "",
                        "Head" : "",
                        "Speed" : ""
                       },
        "Time" : ""
        };
    ]
    */

// onSuccess Geolocation
    function onSuccess(position){
        // Testing for data
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 
        'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />' +
        'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '<br />' +
        'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '<br />' +
        'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '<br />' +
        'Timestamp: ' + new Date(position.timestamp) + '<br />' +
        '<hr />' + element.innerHTML;

        // Puts into JSON Object
        geoLocJSON.id = JSONID;
        geoLocJSON.geoLoc.Lat = position.coords.latitude;
        geoLocJSON.geoLoc.Long = position.coords.longitude;
        geoLocJSON.direction.Alt = position.coords.altitude;
        geoLocJSON.direction.Head = position.coords.heading;
        geoLocJSON.direction.Speed = position.coords.speed;
        geoLocJSON.Time = new Date(position.timestamp);

        // Increments the JSONID
        JSONID++;
    }
```

This will then be posted to the server after 1 minute of collecting data and the JSON Object will be erased UNLESS the POST is unsuccessful, then the object will be stored locally to the device and posted later when a network is available again.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var JSONID = 0;


// Create a JSON Object Array
var geoLocJSON = new Array();

/* This is what I want my Object to look like.
[   
    {
    "id" : 0,
    "geoLoc" : {
                    "Lat" : "",
                    "Long" : ""
                },
    "direction" : {
                    "Alt" : "",
                    "Head" : "",
                    "Speed" : ""
                   },
    "Time" : ""
    };
]
*/

// onSuccess Geolocation
function onSuccess(position){
    // Testing for data
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 
    'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
    'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />' +
    'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '<br />' +
    'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '<br />' +
    'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '<br />' +
    'Timestamp: ' + new Date(position.timestamp) + '<br />' +
    '<hr />' + element.innerHTML;

    var myJSON = {
        "id":JSONID,
        "geoLoc":{
            "Lat":position.coords.latitude,
            "Long":position.coords.longitude
        },
        "direction":{
            "Alt":position.coords.altitude,
            "Head":position.coords.heading,
            "Speed":position.coords.speed
        },
        "Time":new Date(position.timestamp
    };

    // Increments the JSONID
    JSONID++;
    geoLocJSON.push(myJSON);
}
```